# Using hash to check flat file for user login

Tags: perl, mod-perl

I have a user login that I am working on and I am trying to use a hash key assignment to check a flat file to see if the entered password matches the stored one. However, I don't have a very good idea of what I am doing so some guidance would be awesome. The code that I have provided is working correctly however there are things within it that should be updated to a more modern style of Perl programming, I just don't know how to do that.
http://codepad.org/YYGmdknl

Comment: This type of question is not really on-topic for SO, which is intended for specific questions about specific issues.  This probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: the main thing I am concerned about is the issue with getting the hash lookup working. After that I can fix everything else myself, I just had to dumb the rest of the code down so it would actually run.

Comment: As I said the first time, that type of question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you saying the code doesn't work? It sure is dirty, but it looks like it should work.

Fixes:

```
use strict;    # Always use this!
use warnings;  # Always use this!

my $user     = ...;
my $password = ...;

my %passwords;
open(my $fh, '<', 'password.txt') or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
   chomp;
   my ($user, $password) = split /:/;
   $passwords{$user} = $password;
}
close($fh);

if (exists($passwords{$user}) && $password eq $passwords{$user}) {
   print p("Hello"." ".$user);
} else {
   print p("Login failed.");
}
```

But why the hash?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $user     = ...;
my $password = ...;

my $logged_in;
open(my $fh, '<', 'password.txt') or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
   chomp;
   my ($file_user, $file_password) = split /:/;
   if ($user eq $file_user) {
      if ($password eq $file_password) {
         $logged_in = 1;
      }

      last;
   }
}
close($fh);

if ($logged_in) {
   print p("Hello"." ".$user);
} else {
   print p("Login failed.");
}
```